# custom module warnings and errors

Tags: ajax

I have a fairly complex custom module that I'm trying to troubleshoot. The module runs several functions that get called on a user action via AJAX. The issue is that Drupal gives me a bunch of warnings and notices that various variables are undefined. However, I get these warnings and errors on page load - before the user has done anything. It almost seems like Drupal is running through all these functions and when the page loads, rather than when it's supposed to. I could simply edit `php.ini`, but I'd like to understand *why* Drupal would be calling these functions.

Comment: At a guess they're messages left over in the session from the previous AJAX call. You can confirm this by closing the browser, opening it again and re-navigating to the page. If you see no message, then invoke the AJAX, refresh the page, and do see a message, that's what's happening

Comment: I've been seeing these messages for a while - different browsers, sessions, etc. I'm just taking the time now to address it.

Comment: Yep, it'll happen in every browser you use for the same reason

Comment: then how to fix it?

Comment: Fix the warnings and the messages will disappear

Comment: why would the messages be left from the previous ajax call?

Comment: Because messages are stored in the session; unless `drupal_get_messages()` is called (which usually happens by way of `theme_status_message()`), they won't be cleared